# How do I make the checkboxes work separately for each list item?

Tags: javascript

I've appended checkboxes to each appended list item. I'm trying to get each checkbox to work distinctly for each list item, but when I click the checkbox, all of the list items get struck through. I am thinking the solution requires creating a for loop to create distinct id's for each appended list item, but I'm having trouble accomplishing this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
var inputtedChoreVar= document.getElementById("inputtedChore");
var toDoListVar= document.getElementById("toDoList");

var toDoArray= [];

document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',hitSubmit);

function hitSubmit() {

  let x= inputtedChoreVar.value;
  toDoArray.push(x);
  console.log(toDoArray);

  localStorage.setItem('toDoKey', toDoArray);

  var newListElement= document.createElement('LI');
  var newTextNode= document.createTextNode(x);
  newListElement.appendChild(newTextNode);
  toDoListVar.appendChild(newListElement);

  var fButtonElement= document.createElement('input');
  fButtonElement.setAttribute('type','checkBox');
  newListElement.appendChild(fButtonElement);
  fButtonElement.onclick= strike;

  function strike() {
    document.getElementById('toDoList').style.textDecoration='line-through';
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post more of the code? Where does `x` come from? Is that inside a loop or something? EDIT: You also have and extra bracket and it is not clear where `toDoListVar ` comes from too.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question. Entire code for my to-do list posted in original question as an edit. And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `strike()` function is setting a style on the entire `toDoList` element. You probably want to scope that to your `LI`.

```
var inputtedChoreVar= document.getElementById("inputtedChore");
var toDoListVar= document.getElementById("toDoList");

var toDoArray= [];

document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click',hitSubmit);

function hitSubmit() {

  let x= inputtedChoreVar.value;
  toDoArray.push(x);
  console.log(toDoArray);

  localStorage.setItem('toDoKey', toDoArray);

  var newListElement= document.createElement('LI');
  var newTextNode= document.createTextNode(x);
  newListElement.appendChild(newTextNode);
  toDoListVar.appendChild(newListElement);

  var fButtonElement= document.createElement('input');
  fButtonElement.setAttribute('type','checkBox');
  newListElement.appendChild(fButtonElement);
  fButtonElement.onclick= function() { strike(newListElement); } // function that calls "strike" with an argument
}

function strike(el) {
  el.style.textDecoration='line-through';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I had some recognition that I was setting a style to the entire toDoList element because any checkbox would put a line-through all of the list items, but I didn't know how to scope it to the 'LI'. I've been struggling with manipulating appended DOM elements. I think your explanation will help steer me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should apply the style to the li element and not the whole list.

```
function strike() {
    newListElement.style.textDecoration='line-through';
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to rewrite your code in the following way:

Your first issue was that you was assigning the `text-decoration` property to the `toDoListElement` and each children was inheriting it.

You don't need to loop or to assign multiple different ids because JavaScript will save variable references for you (if you use the local variable `newListElement` inside your event handler, when the handler is executed it will use the last value that the variable had).

```js
let inputElement = document.getElementById("inputElement");
let toDoListElement = document.getElementById("toDoList");

document.getElementById('subButton').addEventListener('click', hitSubmit);

function hitSubmit() {

    let newListElement = document.createElement('li');
    let checkboxElement = document.createElement('input');

    checkboxElement.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
    checkboxElement.addEventListener('change', function strike(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            newListElement.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        } else {
            newListElement.style.removeProperty('text-decoration')
        }
    });
    checkboxElement.style.marginLeft = '10px';

    newListElement.innerText = inputElement.value;
    newListElement.appendChild(checkboxElement);
    toDoListElement.appendChild(newListElement);

}
```

```html
<input id="inputElement"></div>
<button id="subButton" type="button">ADD</button>
<div id="toDoList"></div>
```

Finally, for the `localStorage` part, I didn't include it in the snippet, but I would use the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('toDoKey', JSON.stringify((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toDoKey')) || []).concat([inputElement.value])));
```

You was passing the array directly to `localStorage.setItem()` which only accepts string values (for that you use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`)

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code is also clarifying another issue I was having which was removing the text-decoration upon unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: @DavidJang you welcome. Please check my last edit for additional info. When you finish evaluating the answers, remember to choose one.

Comment: Thanks Ernesto. I appreciate it very much.